# JavaScript - Generate a random number between 1 and 5, but never the same number twice consecutively

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math, random

I have some simple code to generate a random number between 1 and 5.
Depending on what number is pulled, a certain sound file will play. However, how could I prevent this simple program from generating the same number twice in a row consequently making the same audio to play twice?
For example: a roll of the dice is never the same twice consecutively, meaning you cannot roll a 2 if you just rolled a 2 etc.

I was experimenting with if else statements and kind of backed myself into a corner. I know this may seem like a simple problem but I'm at my wits end on this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 5.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">ROLL DICE</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just use a variable to store the previous number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get a new number and compare with the old one, if it's the same one, get a new one and repeat. a little recursuion could help here!

```
let lastNumber // start with undefined lastNumber

function getRandNumber() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1); // get new random number

  if (x === lastNumber) { // compare with last number
    return getRandNumber() // if they are the same, call the function again to repeat the process
  }
  return x // if they're not the same, return it
}
function myFunction() {
   const number = getRandNumber()
   lastNumber = number 
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a list to pick from with the last number removed?

```
lastNumber = 0; // Initialize it to a number outside the list so first pick is from full five.
sourceList = [1,2,3,4,5];

function noRepeatRandom(){
    nextList = sourceList.filter(function(x){return x!=lastNumber});
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nextList.length);
    lastNumber = nextList[randomIndex] 
    return lastNumber
}
```

This should pick from the full five for the first call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lastRoll = null;
function myFunction() {
  var thisRoll = lastRoll;
  while (thisRoll === lastRoll) {
    thisRoll = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = thisRoll;
  lastRoll = thisRoll;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 5.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ROLL DICE</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var curr = 0; 

function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

  if(x == curr) {
    myFunction();
  }
  else {
    curr = x; 

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

This should do it if you don't mind using a global variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrb837p/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 5.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ROLL DICE</button>
<span id="previousNumber" style="display:none"></span>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = getRandomNum();
  var temp = document.getElementById("previousNumber").innerHTML;
  while(x == temp){
      x = getRandomNum();
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("previousNumber").innerHTML = x;
}

function getRandomNum(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    return x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple math trick to exclude excessive random calls:

In the first time generate random in range 1..5

In the next times call random in range **1..4**, add it to the current value and use modulo operation - to preserve result range 1..5 but exclude current value

[Code](https://ideone.com/Ynbmy8)  (note it uses x in range 0..4 but output is shifted by one to simplify math)

```
var s = ""
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  s = s + (x + 1) + " "
  x = (x + Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1 )) % 5;   
}
print(s)

1 4 3 2 1 5 4 5 2 1 4 2 4 5 1 4 3 1 4 5 2 1 3 5 2 4 5 3 1 5 3 5 4 5 1 5 3 5 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that you can use. It's quite simple:

min: minimum range;
max: maximum range;
length: how many numbers to generate.

Function and usage:

```
const randomUniqueNumbers = (min, max, length=1) => 
{
    const limit = max-min+1;
    if (min > max || max < min){
       throw new Error(`Parameter "min" has to be smaller than "max" and vice-versa.`)
    }
    else if (length > limit){
      throw new Error(`The length between ${min} and ${max} cannot exceed ${limit}.`)
    }

    let uniqueNumbers = [];
    let number;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        do
            number = Math.floor(Math.random() * limit) + min;
        while(uniqueNumbers.indexOf(number) !== -1);

       uniqueNumbers[i] = number;
    }

    return uniqueNumbers;
}

console.log(randomUniqueNumbers(20, 30, 3)); //[24, 27, 26]
console.log(randomUniqueNumbers(100, 1000, 5)) //[865, 438, 798, 247, 232]
console.log(randomUniqueNumbers(1, 5, 5)) //[5, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```